# How to prevent clipping of dual axis bar chart in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a dual-axis line and bar plot but the end bars are getting clipped. I would like to prevent this from happening without changing the x limits.
This is what I am trying to recreate:-
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp0CE.png)

**The line plot should be in front of the bar plot.**

The code I have used is as follows:-

```
pivot_df.index=pivot_df.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pivot_df.loc[:,['A','B','C']].plot.bar(stacked=True, color=colors,ax=ax)#Bar Plot
ax2 = ax.twinx()
pivot_df.loc[:,['Contribution_B', 'Contribution_C']].plot(ax=ax2,color=colors2,marker='o') #Line Plot
ax2.set_ylim(0,100)
```

Comment: Could you include an image of the issue AND what you are "trying to recreate"? Is the image you linked the issue or what you are referencing?

Comment: Yes, I have circled the issue in the linked image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the call to the second plot is changing the limits of the x-axis. Maybe try to to get the limits before the 2nd plot, and then restore them after

```
pivot_df.index=pivot_df.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pivot_df.loc[:,['A','B','C']].plot.bar(stacked=True, color=colors,ax=ax)#Bar Plot
xlims = ax.get_xlim()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
pivot_df.loc[:,['Contribution_B', 'Contribution_C']].plot(ax=ax2,color=colors2,marker='o') #Line Plot
ax2.set_ylim(0,100)
ax2.set_xlim(xlims)
```